# Mac OS Terminal Find Specific Keyword image and Copy

Tags: terminal, exiftool

I have tons of photo's and I assign a keyword called "background" to photo's that I want as my background.
My Photo's are located in a folder called "Photos" that folder had lots of sub folders.

Is there a terminal command that finds all photo's in folder "Photos" that have the keyword "background" and copy those photos to let's say "Folder B"?

I do have Exiftool by the way, that might help.

Ralph

edit:
'Achtergrond' means Background

I tried now: `exiftool -o ~/test/MapA -if '$Subject=Achtergrond' ~/test/MapB` 
Also tried with this:
`-if '$Subject eq "Achtergrond"'`

```
exiftool -G1 -a -s -api MDItemTags=1 File.jpg| grep Achtergrond
[MacOS]         MDItemKeywords                  : Achtergrond
[XMP-dc]        Subject                         : Achtergrond

exiftool File.JPG  | grep Achtergrond
Subject                         : Achtergrond
```

and I tried:

```
exiftool -o ~/test/MapA -if '$XMP-dc:Subject eq "Achtergrond"' ~/test/MapB 
    1 directories scanned
    0 image files read
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic command to do this with exiftool would be
`exiftool -o '/path/to/Folder B/' -if '$Keywords=~/background/i' /path/to/Photos/`

You do need to check where your keywords are actually stored.  Depending upon what program you used to tag them, the background tag might be stored in `XMP:Subject`, `IPTC:Keywords`, or `MDItemKeywords`.  Maybe even `MDItemUserTags`, I'm not overly familiar with how the Mac system tags works.

I'd suggest running
`exiftool -G1 -a -s -api MDItemTags=1 FILE.JPG`
on a file that you know contains the "background" tag and looking for that tag that contains "background".  If it's something other than `Keywords`, then replace `Keywords` in the above command with that tag name

Breakdown of the above command:
[`-o '/path/to/Folder B/'`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#o-OUTFILE-or-FMT--out): This tells exiftool to copy files to the path `'/path/to/Folder B/'`.  The trailing slash is needed if the output directory doesn't already exist, as otherwise exiftool will just create a file named "Folder B".  Quotes are need around the path if there are spaces in it or the spaces need to be escaped with a backslash.

[`-if '$Keywords=~/background/i'`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#if-NUM-EXPR): This performs a case insensitive RegEx check on the `Keywords` tag to see if it contains "background".  If it does, then the command will be executed on that file, otherwise that file will be skipped.

Comment: I believe you have your directories backwards.  The `-o` option indicates where to copy the files to.  So in your last command, you are searching through directory `MapB` for files to copy to `MapA`.  It appears from the output message there are no files in `MapB`.  As for the other attempts, using an equal sign `=` won't work as that is a numeric operation.  Using `eq` should work if there is no other keywords, as it is an exact string match. But if there is even one additional keyword, it will fail as it will no longer be an exact match.

Comment: ahhhh that's it, you're right, I got in backwards, it works now, thanks a bunch :-)

Comment: If you have any other questions about exiftool, feel free to come over to the [exiftool forums](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/). It's a bit easier to get more detailed answers there.